# Laravel : Unable to insert in database after a transaction has rolled back

Tags: laravel, eloquent, transactions

I successfully use transaction in Laravel to this point : I cannot execute another query after transaction has rolled back.

```php
DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    // DO some stuff

    // Commit transaction
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();

    // This statement has no effect
    DB:insert('something');

}
```

If I execute `DB:insert('something');` just before the transaction, it works fine.
Anything I do wrong ?

No error is thrown. The DB::insert just does not insert anything in the database.

Comment: Please say the error

Comment: and check the : means ```DB::insert('something');```

Comment: try to use : DB::rollBack();

Answer (score 1):

The problem came from elsewhere, sorry for the inconvenience.

For the record, be careful if you use a model instance in your transaction and want to use it after the rollback.

```php
$myModel = MyModel::find(1);
$myModel->someData = 'model to delete';
$myModel->save();


DB::beginTransaction();

try {
    $myModel->delete();
    DB::commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    DB::rollback();

    // This won't work : tries to make an insert
    $myModel->someData = 'some data';
    $myModel->save();

    // This will work : will update the instance
    $myModel = MyModel::find(1);
    $myModel->someData = 'some data';
    $myModel->save();            
}
```